# Old notification code still persistent in app?

Tags: swift, xcode, notifications

I was learning how to add Local Notifications to my app and copy pasted Paulw11's code for testing [How to send a localNotification at a specific time everyday, even if that time has passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821339/how-to-send-a-localnotification-at-a-specific-time-everyday-even-if-that-time-h/38406589)

Now I have a peculiar issue with my app. I have deleted the code from my app but it still sends me daily notifications as if the code is still there. I have deleted and reinstalled the app as well. Could anyone help my figure out how I'm possibly still getting these notifications?

Comment: delete the code again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the solution, rebuild and reinstall, also delete the copied code.